# Weird Exception thrown on HashMap upon iteration

Tags: java, import, iterator, hashmap

I have a problem with a HashMap I have created. When I go to retrieve & iterator from the hashmap so I can iterate over it, I get an exception thrown & I cannot understand what this exception means & how I can fix my error.

The exception is:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator cannot be cast to javassist.bytecode.Descriptor$Iterator
>       at ContentTree.populateTree(ContentTree.java:39)

**Why is this exception being thrown, is there something wrong with my HashMap?**

My code is:

```
public void populateTree( Map <String, UpdatablePage> conMap )
{
    content.removeAllChildren();

    for ( Iterator it = (Iterator) conMap.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) // LINE 39
    {
        Object pageKey = it.next();
```

Comment: Why are you using a non-generic Iterator?  How is Javassist involved here?  This question is woefully incomplete and not answerable in its current form.

Comment: @Jim: It's an honest mistake that sometimes happens when you use the IDE to do your importing.  It's thus easy to see why one wouldn't realize that the import statement is important to include in the question.  No reason to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you importing the wrong Iterator class?  javassist.bytecode.Descriptor.Iterator perhaps?  Again, you should be using generic Iterators as I mentioned in your previous thread. Get the error out of run time and deal with it and fix it at compile time.

Comment: If Javassist is involved it may not be possible to "get the error out of runtime".

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
for ( java.util.Iterator it = (java.util.Iterator) conMap.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); )
```

Comment: I think fixing the import should be sufficient.  This is only needed if he actually needed to use the javaassist class in the same file.  My bet is on a mistaken import.